# How can return filtered data from pipeline in mongodb aggregate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
  p.aggregatePaginate(aggregate, options, function(err, results, pageCount, count) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      if(a){
        if(a === 'xyz'){
          results.docs = results.docs.filter(xyz => !xyz.something)
        }else if (a === 'abc'){
          results.docs = results.docs.filter(abc => abc.something)
        }
      }
      return resolve(results);
    });
```

I want to have the same conditions in aggregate pipeline before project so that I can have filtered data as well as pagination related data too.

I tried doing **cond** in pipeline and inside **cond**, ifNull alternative to **if(a)** then $filter inside but It didn't work as cond doesn't work in pipeline.

It would be a great help if anyone can help me with a better solution. THANK YOU

Comment: Where does `a` come from?

Comment: @Joe a comes from function's parameter

Comment: So before sending the aggregation to the server you could add a different `$match` stage to the pipeline based on the value of `a`, like for 'xyz': `{$match:{something:false}}` and for 'abc': `{$match:{something:true}}`

Comment: But I am adding the field 'something' in the pipeline

Comment: @Joe as the field is not stored in schema and I am adding that in the pipeline, So I can't do that

Comment: perhaps this would make more sense if I could see a sample a couple of sample documents and an example output.